# Функция the_excerpt() выводит не отрывок, а весь контент

Tags: wordpress

```
    <?php if(have_posts()){ 
                    while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
                <div class="article">
                            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <h3 class="display-4"><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <div class="lead">

                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                   </div>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(''); ?>">Далее</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <?php
     } // end While?>

    <?php
        } // конец if ?>
```

Comment: Если excerpt не задан в посте, то по умолчанию выводятся первые 55 слов. Если контент короче, он будет выведен целиком

Comment: так в этом и проблема, он выводит не 55 слов, а весь контент, и когда я ставлю фильтр на 0, то не выводится ничего, а когда на 1, то выводится уже все                                                  
Вот фильтр: add_filter( 'excerpt_length', function(){
 return 1;
} );

Comment: Это не WordPress. Отключите все плагины, смените тему на стандартную - найдите источник ошибки. Потом смотрите фильтры в его коде.